# How to upload a vcard(.vcf) file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to upload a vcard file using codeigniter. But It's not allowed to upload. How to upload a vcard(.vcf) file using codeigniter?

Comment: update this question with what the code you done so far and the error output if any. That will give answerer more information on where the codes are having problems.

Comment: If you are using the file uploading class you have to set the allowed_types parameter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the following to `/application/config/mimes.php` inside the `$mimes` array.

```
'vcf'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
'vcf'   =>  'text/x-vcard'
```

You'll also need to set the `allowed_types` configuration variable for the upload class. An example of setting configuration variables can be found on the [manual page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'vcf';
```

It'd be helpful to know if other file types can be successfully uploaded using your code, see some of what you've tried and also to know what error, if any you're seeing when trying to upload a vcf file.

Answer (score 1):

If the suggestions above didn't work, try this:

```
'vcf' => 'text/plain'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use

```
'vcf'   =>  array('text/x-vcard', 'application/octet-stream', 'text/plain', 'text/directory')
```

for total coverage.